# Dolphin file manager takes 2-3 seconds to load for first use. Is it possible to auto-start it with the system?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I'm using Kubuntu 19.04.

Dolphin is so slow to start for the first use every session. It needs about 2 or 3 seconds to start.

I don't see any error messages if I run `dolphin` from the terminal.

My pc is fairly powerful. So I don't think hardware (16GB RAM, SSD) is an issue.

Is it possible to auto-start Dolphin with the system?

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525328/dolphin-kde-file-management-takes-2-3-seconds-to-load-for-first-use-is-it-possi

Comment: 1. It's [possible](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en). 2. Please don't cross post.

Comment: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/autostart/index.html

Comment: I deleted the other post thanks guys and again sorry for the other post...